# Trouble solving this first-order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

The PDE I'm trying to solve is the following : 
$$(1-xu)u_x-(1-yu)u_y=(y-x)u$$

Using the method of characteristics we have: 
$$x'(t)=1-xu$$
$$y'(t)=yu-1$$
$$u'(t)=(y-x)u=yu-xu$$

A first relationship can easily be derived this way :

$$u'(t)-x'(t)-y'(t)=0\space\space\space(1)$$
$$=>u(t)-x(t)-y(t)=C_1$$

It took me quite some time to get the second relationship in this problem but here's what I found dividing $x'(t)$ with $y'(t)$
$$yux'(t)-x'(t)=y'(t)-xuy'(t)$$
$$=>u[yx'(t)+xy'(t)]=x'(t)+y'(t)$$
$$(1)=>u[yx'(t)+xy'(t)]=u'(t)$$
$$yx=\ln|u|+C_2$$
$$u=e^{yx}+C_2$$

Since $C_2$ will be a function of $C_1$ we get this implicit form:
$$u=e^{yx}+f(C_1)$$
$$u=e^{yx}+f(x+y-u)$$
Is it a problem that u is in the arbitrary function? And if not, how do I apply this result in the PDE to check if it is satisfied?

Comment: It's not a problem, you just have the solution in an implicit form. You can solve for $u$ if boundary conditions are given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little mistake in your calculus :
$$yx=\ln|u|+C_2\quad\text{is OK.}$$
$$u=e^{yx}+C_2\quad\text{is false. It should be :}$$
$$u=c_2\:e^{yx}$$
where $c_2=e^{-C_2}$

As a consequence, the general solution of the PDE, expressed on the form of implicit equation,  is :
$$u=e^{xy}f(x+y-u) \tag 1$$
Without boundary condition, it is not possible to transform the implicit equation into an explicit form.

The function $f$ has to be determined according to some boundary condition(s). Depending on the boundary condition, the solution $u(x,y)$ can (or not) be expressed explicitly.

Nevertheless, one can put this result $(1)$ into the PDE and check if it is satisfied. Compute the partial derivatives such as :

$u_x=ye^{xy}f+e^{xy}f'-e^{xy}u_xf'\quad\text{leading to}\quad u_x=\frac{yf+f'}{e^{-xy}+f'}\tag 2$

$u_y=xe^{xy}f+e^{xy}f'-e^{xy}u_yf'\quad\text{leading to}\quad u_y=\frac{xf+f'}{e^{-xy}+f'}\tag 3$

Then, put $u$ from Eq.$(1)$ , $u_x$ from Eq.$(2)$ and $u_y$ from Eq.$(3)$ into the PDE. Simplify. You will see that it is satisfied.